# How to get the metamask wallet address connected to gnosis safe inside the Safe APP?

Tags: metamask, gnosis-safe, gnosis

I am working on a Gnosis SAFE app. My requirement is that user should connect to the metamask wallet first, deploy a smart contract and then user should proceed with the other task.
I am using [cra-template-safe-app](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-apps-sdk/tree/main/packages/cra-template-safe-app) and following these [Documentation](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-apps-sdk).

For connecting to metamask, I am using [Web3-onboard Package](https://onboard.blocknative.com/). The problem is, inside the Safe APP, metamask connection doesn't works properly. sometimes it connect but sometimes it is not connected to the proper metamask wallet address?

Here is the onboard code which i am using as it is [code](https://github.com/blocknative/web3-onboard)
We have to add manifest.json file to make it compatible to Safe App.
And then i am adding that localhost(on which onboard is running) link to the "Add Custom App" section of Gnosis Safe app.

Another question: I am using [safe-apps-react-sdk package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@safe-global/safe-apps-react-sdk) so, is there any method through which I can fetch metamask wallet address or signer address through this also?